# What does it mean when characters appear on the prompt after an operation?

Tags: bash, escape-characters

Compare the following two commands:

```
mysqldump database_name --hex-blob -uuser_name -p | tee database_name_tee.sql
mysqldump database_name --hex-blob -uuser_name -p > database_name_out.sql
```

If I run the first, on completion I see the following on my terminal:

```
$ 62;c62;c62;c62;c
```

Where does this come from? Does it suggest that something has gone wrong somewhere in the process? Are these control characters which are being output for some reason?

[U+0C62](http://unicode-table.com/en/0C62/) is Telugu Vowel Sign Vocalic L, which I’m pretty sure is not part of my data, so I don’t think this is Unicode. Anyway, the sequence seems to be not `c62` but `62;c`. This could be a control character of some kind. And whatever is causing it is included in the output file. If I later `cat` either `database_name_tee.sql` or `database_name_out.sql`, I again see this sequence once the `cat` is complete.

`tail database.sql -n200` does not produce this output; `-n300` produces just `$ 62;c62;c`; and `-n400` produces `$ 62;c62;c62;c62;c`. So whatever is causing this is distributed throughout the file.

Mucking around with `head` and `tail`, I found one of the culprits: a single line which, when saved to a separate file and printed with `cat`, produces `$ 62;c62;c`. My problem is that this single line is 1043108 bytes.

(The generated SQL file is perfectly fine, and runs without errors. I don’t think that this has anything to do with MySQL per se.)

I’m running the initial `mysqldump` on a CentOS server, and am seeing the same effects from `cat` on both the server itself and my Ubuntu desktop, so this seems to be a general Bash thing.

`od -c problem_line` produces [65174 lines of output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15558893/), so I cut it down to a [smaller section which demonstrates the same output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15559003/) (also available as a [plain hexdump](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15559076/)).

Comment: Could you post (or at least check, if it's too long) the output of `od -c` on the specific line you found? Just save the line in a text file and run `od -c file`. That should help us understand what those characters are.

Comment: @terdon. Thanks for the suggestion. Have added.

Comment: Ugh. Could try narrowing it down a bit? One issue is that you have carriage returns (`\r`) in the file and those can cause characters to appear strangely (since they eat the characters that were printed before them, try `printf 'foo\rbar'`). You also have some weird numbers that probably shouldn't be there. Have a look at what is after `S   h   a   w   n` on line 0002260 of the `od -c` output. Can you extract the surrounding text and see if that reproduces the error?

Comment: Here's a [much smaller section](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15559003/) after playing around with `head -cXX` and `tail -cXX`.

Comment: Yes, you have all sorts of weird characters just after `</a>practice experiences`. Some look like ANSI color escapes. In the output of `od -c`, any column that has more than one character (and isn't things like `\n` of `\t` etc.) is indicative of a problem, or an invisible character of some sort. I can't really tell you more unless you can provide the original file (or, at least, a small part of it that reproduces the error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no escape characters in the octal dump (those would be `033`).

There are a few 8-bit control codes (generally not implemented by most terminals other than xterm).  The octal `232` is hex 0x9a, and (referring to [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-C1-_8-Bit_-Control-Characters)):

```
ESC Z
     Return Terminal ID (DECID is 0x9a).  Obsolete form of CSI c  (DA).

...
CSI Ps c  Send Device Attributes (Primary DA).
            Ps = 0  or omitted -> request attributes from terminal.  The
          response depends on the decTerminalID resource setting.
...
            -> CSI ? 6 c  ("VT102")
```

The characters come from a response by the terminal to the `DECID` control character.  The details of the response depend on the terminal emulator (which was not mentioned in the question).